# Iteration through all features without performance issues when clipping raster

Tags: qgis, raster, pyqgis, qgis-processing, pyqgis-3

I wrote a little script but every time I run it I hit a wall with performance. So in order to iterate through each feature for `gdal:cliprasterbymasklayer` I wrote:

```
from qgis.core import *
import qgis.utils
from qgis.core import QgsVectorLayer
import os
import sys
import numpy as np
from tensorflow.keras.preprocessing import image
import tensorflow as tf
from qgis import processing
from qgis.core import (
     QgsApplication, 
     QgsProcessingFeedback, 
     QgsVectorLayer
)

QgsApplication.setPrefixPath(r"E:\Program Files\QGIS 3.20.1\apps", True)
qgs = QgsApplication([], False)
QgsApplication.initQgis()
sys.path.append(r'E:\Program Files\QGIS 3.20.1\apps\qgis\python\plugins')
import processing
from processing.core.Processing import Processing
Processing.initialize()

def clip_raster_by_vector(input_raster, input_vector, output_raster, overwrite=False):
    if overwrite:
        if os.path.isfile(output_raster):
            os.remove(output_raster)

    if not os.path.isfile(input_raster):
        print ("File doesn't exists", input_raster)
        return None
    else:
        params = {'INPUT': input_raster,
                  'MASK': input_vector,
                  'NODATA': 255.0,
                  'ALPHA_BAND': False,
                  'CROP_TO_CUTLINE': True,
                  'KEEP_RESOLUTION': True,
                  'OPTIONS': 'COMPRESS=LZW',
                  'DATA_TYPE': 0,  # Byte
                  'OUTPUT': output_raster,
                  }

        feedback = qgis.core.QgsProcessingFeedback()
        alg_name = 'gdal:cliprasterbymasklayer'
        result = processing.run(alg_name, params, feedback=feedback)
        return result

request = qgis.core.QgsFeatureRequest()

clause = qgis.core.QgsFeatureRequest.OrderByClause('field_name', ascending=False)
orderby = qgis.core.QgsFeatureRequest.OrderBy([clause])
request.setOrderBy(orderby)
        
shapefile = r'E:\Users\Rodney\test\FinalFilesVienna\test\all_buildings.shp'
layer = QgsVectorLayer(shapefile, 'borders', 'ogr')
it = layer.getFeatures(request)
input_raster = r"E:\Users\Rodney\vienna.tiff"
output_raster = r"E:\Users\Rodney\tmp\tempimage.png"
try: 
    os.mkdir(r"E:\Users\Rodney\tmp")
except:
    print("Dir already exists!")
for idx, feature in enumerate(it):
    layer.select(feature.id())
    _writer = QgsVectorFileWriter.writeAsVectorFormat(layer, r'E:\Users\Rodney\tmp\tempshape.shp', "utf-8", layer.crs(), "ESRI Shapefile", onlySelected=True)
    clip_raster_by_vector(input_raster, r'E:\Users\Rodney\tmp\tempshape.shp', output_raster, overwrite=True)    
    img = image.load_img(output_raster)
    img_array = image.img_to_array(img)
    print(str(idx) + " extracted!")
img_batch = np.expand_dims(img_array, axis=0)
os.rmdir(r"E:\Users\Rodney\tmp")
```

Is there any better solution for iterating through a layer with `gdal:cliprasterbymasklayer` because this script stops working after 7 iterations?

Comment: What do you mean by "hit a wall with performance." You are clipping one raster with each feature in a shapefile?

Comment: i am clipping the raster by a feature at a time from a shapefile to get images of buildings.

Comment: After 7 iterations it gets bugged.

Comment: ah actually its the extraction that gets buggy, i just checked a shapefile that was causing the issues. i am perhaps getting multiple IDs..

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example